# PyMySQL install permission denied

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pymysql

I have Python 2.7, Mysql 5.6 and Mac OSX 10.9, which are all running fine on their own.

I am just wanting to allow python to access my mysql tables (and I am very new at this, so be gentle).

I am trying to install PyMySQL.

I go to my root and enter

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

The install starts, but then I get a permission error. I am the admin on this laptop, so I am not sure what or where to change a permission. The exact error is:

```
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymysql

error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymysql': Permission denied
```

Then it stops.

Suggestions?

PS- I also tried to install MySQLdb, but that was a mess and gave up. So, I am trying pymysql hoping to have better luck.

Thanks

Comment: Run it with `sudo`: `sudo pip install PyMySQL`

Comment: Perfect. Installed. But now import. I went to my python IDE, typed import PyMySQL and get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyMySQL

Comment: In case it was a case sensitive issue I typed- import pymysql, but get the same error.

Comment: Make sure the version of pip you're using is tied to the same version of python you're using -- you're IDE might have its own version of python packaged internally. You can do this by typing `import sys; print sys.path`, and checking that `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` is in the output.